# Como pegar o ip local em shell-script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, linux

Eu estou fazendo um script que precisa do IP da maquina na rede, tentei de várias formas sem sucesso até que descobri uma forma:

```
ip="`ip addr show | grep global | grep -oE '((1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])' | sed -n '1p'`"

echo $ip
```

Funcionou, mas me parece um método muito sujo. Tem alguma outra forma de se fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lembrando que uma mesma máquina pode possuir vários endereços de `IP`. As soluções aqui propostas se aplicam a máquinas `Linux` e retornam somente o endereço de `IP` primário:

1) Utilizando `hostname` + `cut`:

```
$ hostname -I | cut -f1 -d' '
```

2) Utilizando `hostname` + `awk`:

```
$ hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'
```

3) Utilizando `ifconfig` + `grep`:

```
$ ifconfig | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: Eu pegava com o ifconfig, mas o Debian 9 não vem mais com o ifconfig como padrão e não sabia que o hostname mostrava o IP, obrigado mesmo.

Abraço!

Comment: @Everton: Já procurou em `/sbin/ifconfig` ?

Comment: O pacote  net-tools, (que inclui o arp, ifconfig, iptunnel, netstat, route, iwconfig e nameif) foi marcado como obsoleto pela fundação linux e por isso que deixou de ser usado. 

https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/net-tools

Comment: No Debian 9 o bom e velho `ifconfig` ficou obsoleto, agora se usa o comando `ip -stats -color -human addr`

Answer (score 2):

Outra opção

:~$ `hostname -I`

192.168.1.105 172.17.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Mostra todos os IPs:

```
ip addr show | grep global | grep -oE '((1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])'
```

Mostra o principal endereço IP:

```
ip addr show | grep global | grep -oE '((1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])' | sed -n '1p'
```

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso eu precisava pegar um ip fixo, mesmo com ele sem conexão com a internet

Se usar ubuntu 18+
onde fica concentrado seu ip no netplan pode ser usado assim

```
cat /etc/netplant/01-netcfg.yaml | grep "addresses" | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d/ -f1 | cut -d. -f1,2,3,4 |  sed -n '1p' | sort
```